# jquery onclick not firing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

EDIT : Original post removed as have narrowed this down quite a bit.  The orignal post was about trying to dynamically add elements on clicking a button.  Having narrowed it down it doesn't seem to be the code but something else.  I can get the exact same code working on jsfiddle so I must be missing something in my setup somewhere that is causing the click event not to fire/be handled. Again not sure where to look to fix this.
I tried adding some inline and in a js file jquery as below and it works (inline and in js file) without issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");

});
```

The below code however will not fire at all either inline or in js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jpctesting").click(function() {
        alert("this happened");
    });
});
```

The html element is in the php file as below and upon inspect element it exists with the right id etc

```
<input type="button" value="Add Currency" id="jpctesting" />
```

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is bit too unorganized since there are too much of content. But for the question you asked to "dynamically add a field when button clicked" here you could use this function. Imagine you want to dynamically add images to a view. i'm doing it using JQuery.

This is the HTML

```
     <div class="container">
        <!--content goes here -->
    </div>


 <button type="button" onclick="generate_field_with_click()">Click Me!</button>
```

This JS file

```
    var bId = 0;
var imageUrl = "asdasdaimage.jpg"

function generate_field_with_click() {
bId++;
var str = "";

str += "          <div class=\"new__img\">";
str += "            <img  class='nImage'  id=" + 'nIcon' + bId + " src=\"\">";
str += "          <\/div>";

$(".container").append(str);

var id = 'nIcon' + bId;
document.getElementById(id).src = imageUrl;}
```

There you go, This should work to add any field to the DON,Btw be always mindful to create new IDs.

Comment: Thanks. Was a bit of a brain dump so please excuse the waffle - I edited to include code this morning.  Was trying your code but I can't get that working either. I'm actually now just trying using jsfiddle. There are a couple of things I don't understand in your code however - where is 'botIcon' coming from? The second is where is the click event being generated to actually run the function?

Comment: Further to the above when using jsfiddle I can get an alert to pop up without any issues with the exact same code as I'm using on my site.  I'm not sure there is a code problem as such but something else that is causing the click event to not fire. I'm not sure what this would be however.

Answer (score 0):

With the narrowed Question you could try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#jpctesting').on('click', function() {
 alert("this happened");}); });
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it working. There was a few different issues (jquery wasn't being loaded in my plugin - assumed it was ok once sitewide - then when it was loaded it was in the footer....can you tell I'm a complete noob at jquery/js?!).  It's working now and even can get it to add new input boxes (although I've put it down for the day) albeit as there are multiple of the buttons to add this (different products) no matter which one I click the new input boxes are added to the first product.  I haven't looked at it yet but presume need to id the right product area by an id somehow.

Comment: I had to do the below to get it working though. I did try what you have but it didn't work for whatever reason. ````*$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.jpc_mc_add_currency', function() {
  alert("this happend");}); });````